# How do I survive the elevator shaft in Sector 1 of Metroid: Other M?

Tags: metroid-other-m

I'm in this elevator shaft in Sector 1 in Metroid: Other M. It is after the third navigation station. I climb to the top, killing the enemies along the way, and there are some exposed wires at the very top. When I shoot the exposed wires, the elevator moves a bit and it shows me a bad guy climbing up the shaft. I don't know how to kill him before the elevator falls. At first I tried just shooting missles at him, but I wasn't fast enough and the elevator fell on me. So then I tried hiding in one of the open areas on the right side of the shaft and trying to kill the bad guy. But as soon as he got to where I was he'd grab me with his tail and then the elevator would immediately fall on both of us. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot kill the bad guy using conventional weapons or combat tactics. Instead, you must use the very elevator itself to eliminate this impending threat.

What you're shooting is a piece of wreckage blocking the elevator from moving. However, it's not the only piece of wreckage. There is a second one on the side from where you shoot the first.

As you have noticed, there's an open platform on the side, where the elevator can't hit you.

[image: woooah]

However, once you get there, don't try to shoot the enemy coming up the shaft! Instead, look to the other side!

[image: wooooooooooooooaaaaah]

Fire your missiles to destroy this piece of wreckage, and to send the elevator crashing down on your enemy.

Comment: +1 for excellent penmanship and insightful note in second pic.